# NTFS partition is in an unsafe state: failure to boot Windows 8 Lenovo laptop

Tags: windows-8, hard-drive, boot, suspend, hard-drive-failure

I have Lenovo G50-45 that after power on have no signs on the screen, though cpu fan is rotating, that goes to self power off after few seconds of such a state and self power on to repeat the same cycle again.

No another bootable HDD from other laptops is capable to make Lenovo get rid of such rebooting cycle.

In the hope to use Lenovo HDD at least on another machine results in failure to boot Windows 8 although no bootable device is found.

Executing recovery disk on Lenovo HDD inside alive laptop does not help although commands are successful

```
BootRec.exe /fixmbr
BootRec.exe /fixboot
BootRec.exe /scanos
```

Plugging Lenovo HDD to Linux machine results in error

[image: NTFS partition is in unsafe state]

and the following gparted structure

[image: HDD structure]

Is it possible to restore HDD bootability?

Comment: What you’re looking at is an UEFI-bootable drive. Also, Windows is in hibernation. To restore it, you need Windows or Windows Setup. Basically, the question you should ask is “How to restore Windows UEFI boot?”. It’s probably been answered already.

Comment: That is laptop off the shelve without its Windows or Windows Setup disk. Does any Windows 8 version will be able to restore it? e.g. in another language or edition?

Comment: I tried recovery usb created from another Windows Edition installed on different laptop with BootRec.exe but that did not help

Comment: No, of course. You need to modify UEFI boot entries. They don’t use boot sectors at all.

Comment: Are there any disk utilities under Linux or Windows to perform the modification?